# Setting an movieclips image/background

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip

I have a button and a small area which is a movieclip.

What i need is, on button press it inserts an image into the movieClip, it would have to be docked into the whole movieclip area essentially.

I have looked through multiple posts yet they have an overwhelming amount of information that I cannot figure out, this is so far what i have done :

```
B_Background1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setBackground1);

function setBackground1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var firstPic:MovieClip = new C_1BackgroundPIC();

    addChildAt(firstPic, C_MainStage);
}
```

As **I** understand it, it adds an event to the button, then in the function it creates a new movieClip instance which has the Picture inside of it, and then adds it to the "MainStage" although using `C_MainStage` is invalid thus doesn't work, it does add a picture if i just use 0 as the position but it then adds it to the position 0, which i dont want...

Comment: What is **C_MainStage**?

Comment: @Organis A movie Clip on the main Scene, Basically sets the bounds into which the Picture should be fitted in

Answer (score 0):

It's a good start.   When you use `addChildAt`, it expects a number as the second parameter.  Presumably, `C_MainStage` is your MovieClip (which isn't a number).  Presumably you want the current display index of `C_MainStage` (not `C_MainStage` itself).  This can be had by using [getChildIndex](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildIndex())

Look at the following:

```
function setBackground1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    var firstPic:MovieClip = new C_1BackgroundPIC();

    addChildAt(firstPic, getChildIndex(C_MainStage));

    //now, you may need to also resize your picture so it fits in the bounds of C_MainStage, if so, you can do something like this:
    if(firstPic.width >= firstPic.height){
        //if firstPic is wider than it is tall

        //set it's width to the same as C_MainStage
        firstPic.width = C_MainStage.width;

        //now, to keep the aspect ratio (in case they don't match), make the scaleY the same value as the new scaleX
        firstPic.scaleY = firstPic.scaleX
    }else{
        //do the opposite as above since the height is larger than the width
        firstPic.height = C_MainStage.height;
        firstPic.scaleX = firstPic.scaleY;
    }

    //now, you may want to center firstPic in the C_MainStage bounds
    firstPic.x = C_MainStage.x + ((C_MainStage.width - firstPic.width) * .5);
    firstPic.y = C_MainStage.y + ((C_MainStage.height - firstPic.height) * .5)
}
```

Comment: I couldnt seem to get this to work. I commented out the resizing part and then it added a picture but only in the regular position. I can't figure out a fix either

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  Are you getting an error?  What is or is not happening vs. what you are expecting?

Comment: @Flame - So did you figure it out?